# Joining rows based on value conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Assume a Pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
Year         Bread     Amount
-----------------------------
2008S1       white        50
2008S1       brown        30
2008S2       white        60
2008S2       brown        90
2009S1       brown       100
2009S1      golden      2000
2009S2       brown        20
2009S2      golden      1000
```

I wish to join the relevant year/bread combo together such that the amount is added together.  It's okay to assume that every year+bread combo is unique.  So the result would become:

```
Year         Bread     Amount
-----------------------------
2008         white       110
2008         brown       120
2009         brown       120
2009        golden      3000
```

What's a good way to do this?  I thought of using boolean indexing to splice the rows containing *yearS2* and *bread* (deleting the rows and extracting the values). Then look for the relevant rows (*yearS1* and same *bread*) again through boolean indexing, to perform the addition. This sounds like a lot of work which I assume can be handled more elegantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use groupby. Grouping will be done on the first 4 characters of the Year column and the Bread column as follows:

```
df.groupby([df['Year'].str[:4], 'Bread']).sum()
Out: 
             Amount
Year Bread         
2008 brown      120
     white      110
2009 brown      120
     golden    3000
```

Or as regular columns:

```
df.groupby([df['Year'].str[:4], 'Bread'], as_index=False).sum()
Out: 
    Bread  Amount
0   brown     120
1   white     110
2   brown     120
3  golden    3000
```

Comment: This is definitely much cleaner than how I had it in mind.  Superb.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

assuming your DataFrame is in df

```
df.groupby(['year','bread'])['amount'].sum().reset_index()
```